# Database chicken and egg issue

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sybase

I am using Sybase DB with TSQL.

I am trying to work between 2 SPROCS, one nested inside the other.

My outer SPROC will create a temp table `#temp_table` and fill it up with values to 200. Once the temp table has been populated with 200 entries, it will be used by the inner SPROC for a `JOIN`.

So essentially, my outer SPROC will have the following (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table 
(
  ... columns ...
)
```

and my inner SPROC will have the following:

```
SELECT
  SOME_COLUMNS
FROM
  SOME_TABLE
INNER JOIN
  #temp_table
ON
  SOME_CONDITION
```

When I try to test this, I run the script for my inner SPROC and it complains of `#temp_table` not existing, and fails to create the SPROC in the DB. So when I try to go run my outer SPROC, it will also fail.

Could I please get some pointers on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it in two stored procedures. Do it all in one.  A single stored procedure can have as many SQL statements as you need to get the job done, and a temp table is only available within the context of the stored procedure where it's created.

```
CREATE PROC DoItAll
AS

   CREATE TABLE #temp_table 
   (
     ... columns ...
   );

   SELECT
     SOME_COLUMNS
   FROM
     SOME_TABLE
   INNER JOIN
     #temp_table
   ON
     SOME_CONDITION;
```

Comment: Finally I get an answer to this question of mine. This is was my dilemma before. Not only do I have this one join, but I also have a LOT of other SPROCS that also need processing. So if I throw all of them into one SPROC, the one SPROC will grow (perhaps) to several hundred lines. Is this acceptable/good practice?

Comment: That's a bit subjective.  I've seen some monstrous stored procedures.  I hate debugging them, but if it's necessary to have huge stored procedures to get the work done, then it's necessary.

Comment: If I do not do it all in one SPROC, what is another alternative you would suggest?

Comment: I donb't know your situation.  it depends heavily on a number of factors, but if it's possible to use a view instead of a #temptable, there's one option.  Personaly, if I had to do something like that I'd do it in code, in a .NET DataSet - create an in-memory DataTable object instead of creating a temp table at the server, but that's only because it's what I'm most comfortable with.  I don't even know if you're a .NET developer, using another tool, or purely an SQL developer.  Other options get even messier - exporting to a true table, creating it, using it, then dropping it, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I'm working purely with SQL atm and calling SPROCS from shell scripts. I will just put them all into a SPROC.

Answer (score 1):

You can  create table before create procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table 
(
  ... columns ...
)
go

CREATE PROC DoItAll
AS


   SELECT
     SOME_COLUMNS
   FROM
     SOME_TABLE
   INNER JOIN
     #temp_table
   ON
     SOME_CONDITION
go
```

I do it often in my job, to send multiple data between procedures.